# RestFB Searching events by start_time

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb, facebook-events

I am unable to write GET request of the event specifying by start_time.

```
Connection<Event> eventConnection = fbClient.fetchConnection("search", Event.class,
            Parameter.with("q", "york"), Parameter.with("type", "event"), Parameter.with("start_time", "2017-11-11"));
```

I tried to make correct request on restfb but it didn't worked.
[Print screen of this GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjRvW.png).

I would like to make a search events by using RestFB.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can not search events by start time. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search lists what you can search for, and what _by_.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `Parameter.with("since", "2017-11-11")`